# Qt exit application and show another window

Tags: c++, qt

I'm making a qt shooter game and upon detection of collision i want to exit application and show another window with score. This should happen in attack.cpp. How can i do that while the

```
   QApplication a(argc, argv);
   return a.exec();
```

is in main.cpp?

attack.cpp is like this

```
void Attack::move()
{
    QList<QGraphicsItem *> colliding_att=collidingItems();
    for(int i=0; i<colliding_att.size(); ++i){
        if(typeid(*(colliding_att[i]))==typeid(Player)){
            scene()->removeItem(this);
            delete this;

            qDebug()<<SCORE;
          //code that will close the app and open a new window with 
          //text "Your score is"<<SCORE";

            return;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how it can work – `testQWinSeq.cc`:

```
#include <QtWidgets>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  QLabel win1(QString::fromUtf8("GAME"));
  win1.show();
  app.exec();
  win1.hide();
  QLabel win2(QString::fromUtf8("Score"));
  win2.show();
  return app.exec();
}
```

It first opens a window with text "GAME". After closing it, it opens a second window "Score".

---

After reading your question again, I realized that your actual problem might be: How to bail out of the game. Hence, I modified the sample `testQWinSeq.cc` a little bit:

```
#include <QtWidgets>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  // setup 1st GUI
  QPushButton win1(QString::fromUtf8("GAME - Click to Finish"));
  win1.show();
  // install signal handler
  QObject::connect(&win1, &QPushButton::clicked,
    []() { QApplication::quit(); });
  // run
  app.exec();
  // setup 2nd GUI
  win1.hide();
  QLabel win2(QString::fromUtf8("Score"));
  win2.show();
  // run again
  return app.exec();
}
```

I made `win1` a `QPushButton` to simulate the "end of game". (This is what happens in the lambda I connected to the `QPushButton::clicked` signal.)

I simply call [`QApplication::quit()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#quit). So, this name might be a little bit misleading. Actually, it doesn't exit the application. Instead, it exits only the event-loop which is driven inside of `app.exec()`. As you can try yourself, it's not a problem to call `app.exec()` again (and with another main window).

I must admit I could've connected `QApplication::quit()` (without wrapping it in a lambda) as it's signature matches the one of the `QPushButton::clicked` signal perfectly.

I wrote a QMake file `testQWinSeq.pro` to demonstrate:

```
SOURCES = testQWinSeq.cc

QT += widgets
```

and tested in the `bash` of [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) on Window 10 (64 bit):

```
$ qmake-qt5 testQWinSeq.pro

$ make
g++ -c -fno-keep-inline-dllexport -D_GNU_SOURCE -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I. -isystem /usr/include/qt5 -isystem /usr/include/qt5/QtWidgets -isystem /usr/include/qt5/QtGui -isystem /usr/include/qt5/QtCore -I. -I/usr/lib/qt5/mkspecs/cygwin-g++ -o testQWinSeq.o testQWinSeq.cc
g++  -o testQWinSeq.exe testQWinSeq.o   -lQt5Widgets -lQt5Gui -lQt5Core -lGL -lpthread 

$ ./testQWinSeq
```

[image: Snapshot of ./testQWinSeq – 1<sup>st</sup> window]

→ click on button

[image: Snapshot of ./testQWinSeq – 2<sup>nd</sup> window]

```
$
```

A last note:

The `win1.hide();` is essential if the 2<sup>nd</sup> run of `app.exec()` shall only show `win2`. To be sure, I did comment it for testing. If it is not called, there appear both windows in the 2<sup>nd</sup> run of `app.exec()`.